# Where should I add the failover:tcp://host:port?

Tags: activemq-classic

When the network is down, my application should reconnect with the queue. In the documentation of Activemq they say to use the failover:tcp://host:port on the ActiveMQConnectionFactory. But I don't have this class. So, where exactly should I add this command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, my mistake! The class ActiveMQConnectionFactory belongs to apache and the failover should be set on the brokerUrl